# Add Buttons and Graphics in the Same Frame?

Tags: java, graphics

I am creating a program in which users choose options (which are buttons) and ultimately the program should display a graphics output based on their options. I have created the program with the buttons (which works fine) but I was having trouble with the graphics. I was wondering if it is possible to have both graphics (ex: a black rectangle) and the buttons on the same frame. Or, do I need to exit the frame with the buttons and create a new frame with the graphics? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are you able to create graphics w/o the buttons?

Comment: yes, I am able to create graphics and buttons separately. However, when I put it together in the same code, only the button shows up.

Comment: How are you adding the components to the frame?

Comment: I have a separate class to make the graphics using JComponent and paint component. In my viewer class (where the frame is) I add my component from the other class.

Comment: Without a sample, I'm just guessing. I could be completely off base! My suspicion is that you are just calling the 'add' and not really using a layout manager.
This would be a good start - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html